# How to call JChart2D dynamic graph using another JFrame

Tags: java, charts, real-time, jframe

I'm Using JChart2d (http://jchart2d.sourceforge.net/index.shtml) for trace a values of a double array dynamically. when I code the configuration in the main method and run it it run perfectly.

[image]

Here is the code.

```
public  class WaveTracer {

    ITrace2D trace ;
    Chart2D chart ;
    double dataArray [];
    JFrame frame;

public WaveTracer(int limit , double [] data){

trace = new Trace2DLtd(limit);

    dataArray = data;

}

public void configure(String framename, int fwidth , int fheight, int xpos , int ypos ){
    try{

    chart = new Chart2D();

    trace.setColor(Color.RED);

    frame = new JFrame(framename);

    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        /**
         * @see java.awt.event.WindowAdapter#windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent)
         */

        @Override

        public void windowClosing(final WindowEvent e) {

          System.exit(0);

        }

      });

      frame.getContentPane().add(chart);

      frame.setSize(fwidth, fheight);

      frame.setLocation(xpos, ypos);

    }catch (Throwable f) {
      System.exit(0);
    }
}

public void trace(int speed) throws InterruptedException{

    frame.setVisible(true);

    chart.addTrace(trace);

        for (int j = 0; j < dataArray.length; j++) {

          trace.addPoint(j,dataArray[j]);

          Thread.sleep(speed);

         }

    System.exit(0);

}

public static void main(String args []){

      Random random = new Random();

    double d[] = new double[2000];

    int count=1;

    for(int i=200;i>=0;i--){

      d[200-i] = random.nextDouble()*10.0;

    }

         WaveTracer wavetracer = new WaveTracer(5000, d);

         wavetracer.configure("plying wave form with time", 1000, 500, 200, 200);

        try {

            wavetracer.trace(150);

        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {

            Logger.getLogger(FrequencyDitectorForm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

}

}
```

But I need draw the graph when I click on a "Draw" button which in in another form. I created a form which contains a button "Draw" and added the following code to the action click.

```
 JFrame dialog = new JFrame();

 Random random = new Random();

    double d[] = new double[2000];

    int count=1;

    for(int i=200;i>=0;i--){

      d[200-i] = random.nextDouble()*10.0;

    }

WaveTracer wavetracer = new WaveTracer(5000, d);

         wavetracer.configure("plying wave form with time", 1000, 500, 200, 200);

        try {

            wavetracer.trace(150);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FrequencyDitectorForm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

[image]

But when I click on that button only the new frame loads and shows nothing in the frame. Then I have tested the loop by adding a messagebox to the loop. In that case it show the graph for each iteration of the loop.

[image]

Can some one please help me on this issue. How can I get draw this graph from a separate form without triggering a messagebox in every cycle of a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling Thread.sleep(...) on the Event Dispatch Thread or EDT, the main Swing thread that is responsible for drawing and user interaction, and thus putting your whole GUI to sleep.  Don't do this, but instead use a Swing Timer or a background thread.

Also, just a design question: are you sure that you want to display this in a separate JFrame and not a JPanel or if you need a separate window, a JDialog? And are you sure that you want to call System.exit(0) from within the graphing class?

Comment: Hi Hovercraft, Thanks for the tip. I changed it to timers and then remove those system.exit(0) with my code. Now it works fine. Then I have replaced the jFrame with JDialog. Now it works fine. :)

Comment: @Thilanka: glad it helps, but you again might want to accept my answer then and other answers in your previous threads.

Answer (score 1):

are you using the latest version 3.2.1 of jchart2d? I fixed a deadlock related to some "treelock". If so, I had to look closer. Then I'd recommend you submit a bug along with your code.

kind regards, 
Achim